# How do I highlight a table column on selecting a cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I managed to 'highlight' a cell (td-element) when clicked by the user.
I'd like however the whole column to be heightlighted and the cell itself slightly different.
I can't get the last part done (highlighting the whole column).
all help in this is appreciated.

The desired outcome would be something like below:

[image]

```js
function handleBlur(event) {
  event.target.contentEditable = false;
 }
 
 document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if (event.target.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'td') {
   event.target.contentEditable = true;
   event.target.focus();
   event.target.addEventListener("blur", handleBlur);      
    }
 });
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 50px 0 0 50px;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}
th {
  background-color: white;
}

table td[contentEditable=true]{
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 200px rgba(186,210,225,0.51);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 200px rgba(186,210,225,0.51);
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 200px rgba(186,210,225,0.51);
  outline: 3px solid #086AA7;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus </td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari </td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You would have to count which `td` it is, then loop over all `tr`s your table has and apply a style to the x-`td` of each `tr`.

Comment: `event.target.cellIndex` tells you which `td` it is

Comment: The linked possible duplicate shows you a solution in jQuery. You had jQuery as a tag so I assume you are able to use jQuery switching classes on all relevant `td` elements for the same index.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays you can do this easily without jQuery by using the native DOM apis.

Find the index of the selected cell in the children of it's parent (using `cellIndex`), then iterate the cols, and change the background of the relevant `col` in the `colgroup`:

```js
function handleBlur(event) {
  event.target.contentEditable = false;
}

var cols = document.querySelectorAll('col'); // find the cols and cache

document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  var t = event.target;
  if (t.tagName.toLowerCase() !== 'td') {
    return;
  }

  t.contentEditable = true;
  t.focus();
  t.addEventListener("blur", handleBlur);

  var highlightIndex = t.cellIndex; // the index of the clicked item in the row

  cols.forEach(function(col, index) { // iterate the cols
    col.style.background = index === highlightIndex ? 'lightblue' : null; // set the background to the clicked col, remove from others
  });
});
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 50px 0 0 50px;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

table td[contentEditable=true] {
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 200px rgba(186, 210, 225, 0.51);
  outline: 3px solid #086AA7;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <colgroup> <!-- add a colgroup with a col item for each column -->
    <col>
    <col>
    <col>
  </colgroup>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus </td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari </td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```